# openvpn client connection issue

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, openvpn

I have a ubuntu box behind a router, and I have no access to that router.

The router will fail now and then, I don't know why. I can not connect to the internet during the router failure time. However, even after the router function restored, I still can not connect to the internet. I can stop the openvpn client, the my connection to the outside will be back.

is that normal, or there a way to fix it.

I believe I can setup a script to stop and start the openvpn client every so many minutes, it may just work. But I want to know if there is a better way.

Thanks.